# Problema em CkEditor com PHP PDO

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Tenho um script PHP que realiza uma atualização no banco de dados pra alterar as propriedades de css de alguns textos, porém a inclusão está sendo feita da seguinte forma:

```
<h2><span style=\"color:#fff; font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif\">INFORMA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O E MONITORAMENTO, ONDE&nbsp;E QUANDO VOC&Ecirc; PRECISA</span></h2>
```

Ou seja, após o style está incluindo uma contra-barra.

Em todas as páginas que usam o ckeditor estão acontecendo este mesmo erro. Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente está vindo do banco de dados assim. Está escapando as aspas para não causar problemas com a sintaxe do SQL e/ou ajudar a prevenir SQL injection.

Usa `stripslashes`:

> Remove barras invertidas de uma string.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripslashes.php)

Exemplo:

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```